# How to do multi facets search in thinking sphinx rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, facet, thinking-sphinx

Using `thinking-sphinx` for facets in my app and define two facets `price` and `year`.

I want to fetch facets nested results.

Now I am getting facets by year and it give count against year.

```
years = records[:year]
```

Along with the count of records along with year I also want to get min price in that year.

Now I getting it like

```
years.map do |year,count|
     price = Data.where(:year=>year).minimum(:price)
     {count: count,cheapest_price: price}
end
```

But its like LazyLoading as N+1 against year. I want to fetch prices along within year facets.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this code does what you want - though you may need to tweak things to get exactly what you're after:

```
Data.search(
  :select => "groupby() AS year, MIN(price) as min_price, count(DISTINCT sphinx_internal_id) as count",
  :group_by => :year,
  :max_matches => 1000,
  :middleware => ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::RAW_ONLY
)
```

Each option explained:

- The `select` specifies the appropriate aggregations you're after, and `groupby()` is a function that refers to the attribute this query is grouping by.
- `group_by` specifies the attribute you want the query to group by. Sphinx's equivalent of `GROUP BY` in SQL, though in the past it has been more limited.
- `max_matches` should be set to 1000, unless you've configured it to be a higher value in your Sphinx configuration (via `config/thinking_sphinx.yml`). Using the highest possible value ensures the facet results scan as many documents as possible. You could also set `:limit` to the same value for the specific number of rows being returned here.
- `middleware` uses a limited set of Thinking Sphinx middleware classes, to avoid translating results into ActiveRecord objects - instead, you'll get an array of hashes with the Sphinx query data.